# PHP online store, looping buttons & databases

Tags: php, shopping-cart

So I am writing this code and I want to make it by getting the data of the database using a loop. The problem that I got is that I can't seem to find a way to push through a value to the database from the buttons that I got. I am open to ideas. Thanks !

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Online Catalog</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get">

<?php 
session_start();
require('database.php');

echo "<h1><a href=". 'index.php' .">Catalog</a></h1>
<b id=".cart."><a href=". 'cart.php' .">Show cart</a></b>";

if ($result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `store`")) {
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<p>
            <table>
                <th>
                    <img src=".$row[img_path].'/'.$row[img_name].">
                </th>
                <td>
                    <h2>". $row[name] ."</h2><br>
                    ". $row[description] ."<br><br>
                    Price : ". $row[price] ."$<br>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <input type='submit' name='add".$row[id]."' value='Add to cart'/>
                </td>
            </table>
        </p>
        ";

        if(isset($_GET['add.$row[id].'])){
            $cart=1;
            if(mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `store-project`.`store` (`incart`) VALUES ('$cart')")){
                mysqli_close($connection);
                header("Location: cart.php");
            }   
        }
    }


    $result->close();
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HJdg.png)

[And here is how it generally looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr58y.png)

Comment: Hello, Boian, welcome to Stack Overflow. I am sorry, but it is absolutely unclear what you are asking. Please see the tour page and see the help center on how to ask good questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use Post method in your form.

```
if($_POST['add.$row['id'].']){
$insert = "insert into store-project.store           
set incart = '".$cart1."';
mysqli_query($insert);
header("Location: cart.php");
}
```

Hope it helps